# Ant gives CNF issue, if i use <pathelement location="">

Tags: ant

To avoid the long class path issue in windows, i modified my build.xml like[1]
introduced a property called "temp" and referring that from "path location"
But now im getting "Class not found" exception[2].
How can i correct my script?

If i don't use the "temp" property and try to read "temp.classpath" as my "javac" classpath" i get long classpath issue..(That is why i introduced that property and made "javac" path as "javac.classpath")

```
[1]
<target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${class.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="./../../work/temp/sampleClient"/>       
          <path id="temp.classpath">        
            <pathelement path="${class.dir}"/>
            <pathelement path="../../lib"/>         
            <fileset dir="../../repository/components/plugins">             
                <include name="*.jar"/>                 
            </fileset>>
            <fileset dir="../../lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="../../lib/endorsed">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="../../repository/components/extensions">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="../../repository/components/lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>  
             </path>    
        <property name="temp" refid="temp.classpath" />
        <path id="javac.classpath"> 
            <pathelement location="${temp}"/>       
        </path>         
    </target>


[2]

init:

compile:

stockquote:
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: samples/userguide/StockQuoteClient
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: samples.userguide.StockQuoteClient
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ANT to avoid long classpath issue there is  **ManifestClasspath task** available ..I used that and now it is working properly in windows and linux..
I have written a blog[1] entry here with the sample..If anyone find it useful..

http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/04/avoiding-long-classpath-issue-in-ant.html

Answer (score 0):

the  <path> element is a first-class object if you will, so its reference id can be used anywhere a path is expected, with the caveat that it's usually a slightly different property. For isntance:

```
<javac ... classpathref="temp.classpath" >
   ...
</javac>
```

will do just fine.

So you don't need to, and you can't, pass it thru a property.

[EDIT per my comment below]
IF you insist, though, you can try:

```
 <path id="javac.classpath"> 
     <pathelement path="${temp}"/>       
 </path>
```

Notice the path attribute in lieu of location.

Or, if you insist on using the implied javac.classpath reference:

```
 <path id="javac.classpath"> 
     <path refid="temp.classpath"/>       
 </path>
```

Comment: My javac is defined like this;                                <javac srcdir="src" destdir="${class.dir}" includeantruntime="false">   
            <classpath refid="javac.classpath"/>   
        </javac>  as you said if i use "classpathref="temp.classpath" ill get long classpath issue in windows...Im trying to avoid that issue

Comment: Can you please post more details about the "long classpath issue" you're mentioning ? The stack trace is a CNF, I can't really see how you're getting to this conclusion. The main issue with your code sample is that <property name="temp" refid="..." /> can't work because the reference is for a path object, not a property one. So if you're lucky (depending on your version of Ant), the actual path is expanded as a string value in temp. Then you shouldn't be using it as a location, but use the path="${temp}" attribute instead.